# How to enable browser notifications using Cypress

Tags: cypress

I am using Cypress for e2e testing and the site I am testing requires to have the notification permission granted.
For manual testing, I go to chrome preferences->Privacy and Security->Site Settings->Notifications and set the site url to 'Allow'

But how do I do this on Cypress ?

Comment: This blog post [Testing the Browser Notification API](https://www.cypress.io/blog/2020/01/24/testing-the-browser-notification-api/) goes into testing browser notifications in detail. Source code is [here](https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/tree/master/examples/blogs__notification).

Answer (score 0):

To do this on Cypress you need the  `index.html` and then you can do this first test to confirm that the browser support notifications:

```
/// <reference types="Cypress" />
describe('Browser notifications', () => {
    it('are supported by the test browser', () => {
        cy.visit('index.html')
        cy.window().should('have.property', 'Notification').should('be.a', 'function')
    })
})
```

If you enable notifications from Cypress itself, you will see a popup if you click "Notify me!" button.
The rest of the tests stubs Notification constructor to avoid popups

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [cypress-browser-permissions](https://github.com/kamranayub/cypress-browser-permissions)
 plugin.